# Get an email notification on issue count change on JIRA

Tags: jira

I have a jira dashboard which shows the list of issues that fall under a category. 
Is there any way I can configure to get an email notification when a change occurs in the count of these issues?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the perfect solution, as it will not be triggered by "count change", but it is the best you could come up with without writing a custom plugin. Create a subscription on the filter you are using in the dashboard. This will send you the filter results in a fixed interval. https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/receiving-search-results-via-email-720416706.html